# Could not load the assembly. The property 'assembly' must be a valid assembly ASP.NET Website project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, vs-web-site-project

Has anyone seen this:[image]

Only one developer is getting this on our team so it doesn't seem to me something that's checked into source control. Does anyone have any clues as to what to look at?

Comment: This you manage to solve this issue? As I've come across it today

Comment: We ended up copying a working folder from a dev's machine that was known to work. For whatever reason that cleared it up. You may try checking out your code from scratch in a new folder. Unfortunately it's just a guess as we weren't able to determine a root cause.

Answer (score 3):

What solved it for me was the "Run Visual Studio as Administrator".

I found the idea at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0757eb10-826e-472d-b865-0b815779c480/aspnetcompiler-error-can-not-load-assembly-in-msbuild-only?forum=msbuild by @Stephan Golux / @Stephan-G

Also somewhat at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36182890/1662973

I am a local admin on the machine, but this seems to be an old school fix.  Using VS2017.